# Not able to stop event bubbling on my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created an app which will have a button in the start, and on click, it will create a parent div for existing div. Child div should be draggable inside its parent div. When I try to drag child component its parent component are also getting dragged.

Expected solution - [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q-iIEKaypmNUQUdlQkOlytWjjFo1GO1K/view)

My code -

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

function ParentDraggable(props) {
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  const [y, setY] = useState(0);
  

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    let startX = e.clientX;
    let startY = e.clientY;

    const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
      setX(x + e.clientX - startX);
      setY(y + e.clientY - startY);
      startX = e.clientX;
      startY = e.clientY;
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    });
  };

  return (
    <Draggable bounds='parent' handle='.handle' onDrag={e=>e.stopPropagation()}>
    <div
      style={{
        position: 'relative',
        top: y,
        left: x,
        border: '1px solid black',
        width: `${props.w}px`,
        height: `${props.h}px`,
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          height: 20,
          backgroundColor: 'gray',
        }}
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        className='handle'
      >
        Title Bar
      </div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
    </Draggable>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [parents, setParents] = useState([]);
  const [w, setW] = useState(200)
  const [h, setH] = useState(200)

  const handleAddParent = () => {
    setParents([ <ParentDraggable w = {w} h={h}>
     {parents}
    </ParentDraggable>]);
    setW(prev => prev + 100)
    setH(prev => prev + 100)
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleAddParent}>AddParent</button>
    
    <div style={{height: '97vh'}}>
      
      {parents}
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please help me achieve my goal.

Comment: Your event handlers are placed on the `document` object. The events have already propagated, so `.stopPropagation()` is too late.

Comment: If you want per-component listeners you'll need to create them inside a `useEffect()` hook. Then remove them in a `return` from that hook.

Comment: @RandyCasburn could you please write code for this or please suggest me any blog, I trid but not able to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Your additions to Draggable doesn't seem to really do anything. Instead of DIY, what you are missing is `nodeRef()`. The React-draggable docs are not the easiest to read, but there's extra something there if you are interested.

Try this out, you'll want to use something like `useId()` to target the handle and you really need a combo if `useRef()` and `nodeRef()`. You will need to make your "parents" stack again, I hardcoded this one for simplicity.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react"
import Draggable from "react-draggable"

function App() {
  const r1 = useRef()
  const r2 = useRef()

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "97vh" }}>
      <Draggable bounds="parent" handle=".handlea" nodeRef={r1.current}>
        <div
          ref={r1}
          style={{
            border: "1px solid black",
            width: `300px`,
            height: `300px`,
          }}
        >
          <div
            style={{
              height: 20,
              backgroundColor: "gray",
            }}
            className="handlea"
          >
            Title Bar
          </div>

          <Draggable bounds="parent" handle=".handleb" nodeRef={r2.current}>
            <div
              ref={r2}
              style={{
                border: "1px solid black",
                width: `100px`,
                height: `100px`,
              }}
            >
              <div
                style={{
                  height: 20,
                  backgroundColor: "gray",
                }}
                className="handleb"
              >
                Title Bar
              </div>
            </div>
          </Draggable>
        </div>
      </Draggable>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: yes, this is working fine, but how can i create useRef dynamically? I tried that creating inside useEffect and it gives me error 'can't call useRef inside callback'

Comment: could you please write this code as expected solution, I have been trying this for last some days and still not able to code it properly

Comment: @akkad Sorry, that is a lot of coding that I just don't have time for. Even if I did, this is such an unusual use case that it would _really_ help to know the context; exactly why are you doing this? How many layers do you want to support? How do you want the layer sizing to work? The details and context really does matter.

Comment: this was asked in one of my interview but not able to make that time but curious to know solution. I have almost completed tthis here - [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-smoke-erw0tt?file=/src/App.js), only problem is innermost child is chaning its position to top-left of its parent whenever creating new parent div and I want that.Ex - create two div, drag child one to right-bottom corner and click on add parent button then you will find innermost div is in the top-left of its parent but it should be on its place i.e. right-bottom.

Comment: @akkad Ah, I see! Hmm, did they explicitly say to use Draggable? Did they explicitly say to use React? This might be simpler if you just do everything yourself without any kind of library/framework

Comment: They just show me [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q-iIEKaypmNUQUdlQkOlytWjjFo1GO1K/view) and asked to implement. Once I had used react-draggable so I tried that again but not able to implement yet.